# Hide element based on viewport position in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to create an button (arrow) point down to some content below.. if the content below isn't in view an arrow pops up on page load and the user can select it so the page scrolls to this point in the page..

```
    var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);

    // var d = document.document.getElementsByClassName("container");
    var topPos = h.offsetTop;

    if (topPos > 1) {
      $('go-btn_banner').addClass('banner-btn');
    };
```

The above i've tried to find the height of the viewport and set `offsetTop` so if the user can see the content add a class which hides it, if not show it.

Any help how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(window).height()` and `$(window).scrollTop` to figure out where the screen cuts off, and then `$("content query").offset().top` to see where the content starts, and figure out whether or not it's in the window view.

And also, `$(window).on("scroll", function() {})` for the event handler;

Answer (score 0):

Check this out https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible This is a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to check whether an element is in view or not:

```
$.fn.isVisible = function(x, y){

  if(x == null || typeof x == 'undefined') x = 1;
  if(y == null || typeof y == 'undefined') y = 1;

  var win = $(window);

  var viewport = {
    top : win.scrollTop(),
    left : win.scrollLeft()
  };

  viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
  viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

  var height = this.outerHeight();
  var width = this.outerWidth();

  if(!width || !height){
    return false;
  }

  var bounds = this.offset();
      bounds.right = bounds.left + width;
      bounds.bottom = bounds.top + height;

  var visible = (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));

  if(!visible){
    return false;   
  }

  var deltas = {
    top : Math.min( 1, ( bounds.bottom - viewport.top ) / height),
    bottom : Math.min(1, ( viewport.bottom - bounds.top ) / height),
    left : Math.min(1, ( bounds.right - viewport.left ) / width),
    right : Math.min(1, ( viewport.right - bounds.left ) / width)
  };

  return (deltas.left * deltas.right) >= x && (deltas.top * deltas.bottom) >= y;
};
```

And then use it like this:

```
if ($('go-btn_banner').isVisible(0.8, 0.8)) {
  $('go-btn_banner').addClass('banner-btn');
};
```

Which will require the `$('go-btn_banner')` to be `80%` visible in order for the `if` statement to execute. To check if an element isn't in view either connect an `else` statement to this or do:

```
if (!$('go-btn_banner').isVisible(0.8, 0.8)) {
  $('go-btn_banner').addClass('banner-btn');
};
```